# Referencing calling instance variable when extending has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, model-associations, rails-models

I have a model called `Project` that has many `Proposals.`

The Project model has an attribute called `winning_proposal_id`

Right now I have something like this to find the winning proposal as well as a has_many for proposals:

```
belongs_to :winning_proposal, :class_name => "Proposal", :foreign_key => "winning_proposal_id"
has_many :proposals, dependent: :destroy
```

from which I do:

```
@project.winning_proposal
```

to reference the winning proposal, but I'm not really a fan of this.

What I would prefer would be something like this:

```
@project.proposals.winner
```

which I think it just cleaner.  To do this, however, I need to be able to reference the instance variables winning_proposal_id from within the block:

```
has_many :proposals, dependent: :destroy do
  def winner
    self.where(id: winning_proposal_id).first
  end
end
```

but that doesn't work.  I believe I could do this:

```
has_many :proposals, dependent: :destroy do
  def winner
    self.where(id: self.project.first.winning_proposal_id).first
  end
end
```

but that seems kludgy.  Anyone know how to reference the calling instance variable from within the block?

Comment: Interesting. It's probably a matter of taste, but I prefer the @project.winning_proposal way. It has the additional advantage of following the Law of Demeter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: True.  I just find this cleaner.  Makes it easier to do things like project.proposals.winner and project.proposals.loser`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone else interested:

```
has_many :proposals, dependent: :destroy do
 def winner
  self.first(conditions: {id: proxy_association.owner.winning_proposal_id})
 end
end
```

The key is to use the `proxy_association.owner` to reference the parent.